# Complex case values in Swift

Tags: select, swift

Swift has a rather nifty `switch` statement by the looks of it (at least compared to the other C derivatives) in that you can use values, lists, tuples, ranges and so on.

Its sequential processing nature makes this a very logical approach, but I'm wondering whether it supports more arbitrary objects for checking against, such as variables and other general expressions, such as with:

```
let check = 7
switch (value) {
    case check:
        println("exact");
    case check * 2:
        println("twice");
    case check * 3:
        println("thrice");
    case valueInDb("mytable","mycolumn"):
        println ("value in database");
    default:
        println("some other value");
}
```

Comment: But of course!  It might be a bit inefficient to use expressions like this rather than constants because they have to get re-evaluated for each call, but it is definitely possible.  You can go even further and override `~=` to compare against other objects and values.

Comment: @CodaFi, it's not obvious from the doco on the Apple site since all examples and descriptions seem to use constant values in the `case` stanza. If it _does_ allow expressions, you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is called "Expression Pattern"

From [this document](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-XID_1020):

> An expression pattern represents the **value of an expression**. Expression patterns appear only in switch statement case labels.
>
> The expression represented by the expression pattern is compared with the value of an input expression using the Swift standard library `~=` operator. The matches succeeds if the `~=` operator returns true. By default, the `~=` operator compares two values of the same type using the `==` operator.
>
> ...
>
> > `expression-pattern` → `expression­`

So you can use any "expression" in switch case, and **by default**, it will be compared using `==` operator.